# Databound Listpicker blank entries

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-toolkit, listpicker

I have just started trying to build my first wp7 app, and I am learning c# and xaml from scratch.
I have made good progress but I am having trouble with the silverlight toolkit listpicker.

I databound a list picker using the following template

```
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="pitVolume">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Litres}"  Margin="12 0 0 0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

bound to this:
    List concunitsource = new List();

```
            concunitsource.Add(new Units() { Molar = "pM", Factor = -12});
            concunitsource.Add(new Units() { Molar = "nM", Factor = -9, Grams = "ng"});
            concunitsource.Add(new Units() { Molar = "µM", Factor = -6, Grams = "µg", Litres = "µL" });
            concunitsource.Add(new Units() { Molar = "mM", Factor = -3, Grams = "mg", Litres = "mL" });
            concunitsource.Add(new Units() { Molar = "M", Factor = 0, Grams = "g", Litres = "L" });
```

The listpicker binds but I get two small blank but selectable entries at the top (presumably space for pico and nano litres). I left these out as they would not get used by the user.
Is there anyway to prevent this, and just show the 3 that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a few ways but there are probably more:

The simplest would be to not load items in the ListPicker that won't be displayed.  Or use Linq-to-Objects to filter out the items you want displayed to the collection that is bound to the control.

```
dspConcunitsource = concunitsource.Where(u => u.Litres != null).ToList();
```

You might look at using a [CollectionViewSource](http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2010/10/14/wp7-in-app-searching-filtering.html) to filter out items in the collection you don't want displayed based on some criteria.

Comment: wow thanks so much, worked a treat. as i said I only started this week and it would be nice to understand why this works so i can apply it in the future. for example what does the "u" mean?

Comment: this might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx , that can also be written like a regular loop.  So, foreach (var u in Units) {}